# Why `NotificationCenter+Rx` is in RxCocoa not RxSwift

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Since [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) is a part of [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation). I expect it should be within RxSwift, not RxCocoa.

But why [NotificationCenter+Rx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/f043778214c8f182018ccdfbf7f440edbe0aecc8/RxCocoa/Foundation/NotificationCenter%2BRx.swift) is in RxCocoa? Any reason behind that?

In some of our project, we only use RxSwift without RxCocoa. If we use `NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification`, we will get the error `Value of type 'Reactive<NotificationCenter>' has no member 'notification'` because NotificationCenter+Rx is in RxCocoa only.

Comment: As far as I can see, RxSwift only implements observable properties on types in the Swift standard library, which does not include Foundation.

Comment: @Palle good call, I think the goal of RxSwift is targeted to the platform-independent Swift. Foundation doesn't work on non-Apple platforms like Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is - RxSwift, RxJava etc are the platform-agnostic implementations of the [ReactiveX.io](https://reactivex.io) standard, e.g. - Observables, Operators, Subjects, etc.

While the platform-*specific* things are, well, platform-specific ;-) In our case, RxCocoa covers NotificationCenter which isn't relevant to other, non-Cocoa platforms.

Comment: Thanks @shai-mishali, because RxSwift can run on non-Apple platforms, I think that's OK to make it in RxCocoa. I would like to separate Foundation and UIKit if possible though. I mark it as the answer now and hope to help the others have the same concern.